# hash in url to deep linking with ajax

Tags: ajax, hash, tags, deep-linking

I've this code to load content in a div #target with some animation. Works fine but i don't know how implement code to change link and url with #hash!
How can I do  this?

the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#target").addClass('hide');

  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function() {   
    var pagina = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('#target').is(':visible')) {

    }
    $("#target").removeClass('animated show page fadeInRightBig').load(pagina, 
      function() { 
        $("#target").delay(10).transition({ opacity: 1 })
          .addClass('animated show page fadeInRightBig');                        
      }
    );
    return false; 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any javascript router. For example, [router.js](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/RouterJs).

Modify you code like this(I didn't check if this code work, but I think idea should be clear):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var router = new Router();

  //Define route for your link
  router.route('/loadpath/:href', function(href) { 
    console.log(href);
    if ($('#target').is(':visible')) {
      $("#target").removeClass('animated show page fadeInRightBig').load(href, 
        function() { 
          $("#target").delay(10).transition({ opacity: 1 })
            .addClass('animated show page fadeInRightBig');                        
        }
      );
    }
  });

  router.route('', function(){ console.log("default route")});


  $("#target").addClass('hide');

  // Instead of loading content in click handler, 
  // we just go to the url from href attribute with our custom prefix ('/loadpath/').
  // Router will do rest of job for us. It will trigger an event when url hash is        
  // changes and will call our handler, that will load contents 
  // from appropriate url.
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function() {
    router.navigate('/loadpath/' + $(this).attr('href'));   
    return false; 
  });
});
```